# Количество минут между двумя датами

Tags: javascript, дата, время

Есть три переменных:

```
var start = '12.04.2018 15:00';
var finish = '12.04.2018 17:00';
```

Подскажите, как посчитать количество минут между этими двумя датами?
Что-то вроде такого:

```
var minutes = calcMinutes(start, finish); // результат - 120
```

Comment: перевести строки в даты и подсчитать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так:

```js
var start = '12.04.2018 15:00'; 
var finish = '12.04.2018 17:00';

function calcMinutes(start, finish) {
  return ((new Date(finish)).getTime() - (new Date(start)).getTime())/60000;
}

var minutes = calcMinutes(start, finish);
console.log(minutes);
```

Только формат в js MM.DD.YYYY

Comment: даты можно просто вычитать, не обязательно `getTime` вызывать

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с датами можно использовать библиотеку [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/), которая предоставляет множество дополнительных методов, в том числе [diff](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/), с помощью которого можно получить разницу между двумя указанными датами:

```js
let date1 = moment('2018-06-13T00:00:00+08:00')
let date2 = moment('2018-06-13T00:05:00+08:00')
let diff = date2.diff(date1, 'minutes')
console.log(diff)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Покажите еще как задавать свой формат для входящих данных, чтобы это работало с исходными данными в вопросе

Comment: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/